# Regarding the pronunciation of "address"

Tags: pronunciation

[pronunciation of address](https://forvo.com/word/address/#en)

I'm a post-80s. I had been keeping pronouncing it /əˈd'drɛs/ for many years until recently. Now I know its pronunciation in verb form /əˈdrɛs/ and noun form /ædrɛs/.
I thought what had made me misread it was becase our teacher misread it.
But today, my older leader (a Chinese) also read it as /əˈd'drɛs/. This pronunciation is more a 'd' in there. It didn't look like both our teachers misread it. I wonder where did the 'a d dress' pronunciation come from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a native *British* English speaker I can tell you that both the noun and verb are pronounced exactly the same. Listen to the audio pronunciation on [this](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/address) dictionary site. I was aware that US English speakers pronounce the noun differently, but going off the US English pronunciations on the same site, it would seem that Americans pronounce both the noun and the verb the same as well.

- British English speakers pronounce it to sound like "*a dress*"
- US English speakers pronounce it to sound like "*add ress*"

Perhaps your confusion comes not from hearing the noun and verb pronounced differently, but hearing them in different accents or dialects?

In both countries, there are also varying *regional dialects. The vowel sound at the start of "address" may sound like "uh" or "eh" in some British regional accents.

Comment: AmE speakers are divided in respect to the noun.  uh-DRESS and AD-dress.   If the verb refers to writing a street address on an envelope, it can have either pronunciation. But if it means to tackle or confront a problem, the verb is pronounced uh-DRESS. *We have to uh-DRESS the problem of global warming*.

Answer (score 1):

The confusion comes from the use of the word being used as a noun (address) and as a verb (to address). The noun address, which is the location of a residence, is pronounced with the emphasis on the 'a'dress - sounds like the a in actor "a-dress." Ex. My address is 10 Fillmore Street"
The verb "to address," as an envelope or address an audience, bears the accent or stress on the last syllable - uh-dress. If it were to be written with accent marks as in Spanish, the noun "address" would be written as áddress and the verb "to address" as addréss. Ex. The post office needs to address the issue of writing the address on an envelope using cursive writing.

Comment: Not true  The verb and noun are pronounced exactly the same way

Comment: You're both wrong and both right, because you are not limiting your statements geographically. See Astralbee's answer